# Angular App primeng FileUpload slow on Chrome only

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I have an angular application that uses **primeng** for **FileUpload**, and recently we have experienced the "Choose" button being very slow in opening up a file explorer in Chrome.

I don't suspect is is a code issue because using firefox, this file explorer window opens immediately.

Something interesting is I notice this same behavior using Angular's own page.

**https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload**

When clicking "Choose", I get an immediate response using firefox, and then using chrome, it locks up my browser and takes about 5 seconds before the file explorer window opens. There is no code in this question and I can't imagine it's a code issue given the same behavior on my app and angular website.

So the question is, what are some possibilities or areas that I should look at?

Sorry for the vague question, but a bit puzzled by this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running the latest version of Chrome on Windows 10 64-bit, and I don't experience a 5-second delay. There does seem to be some kind of flickering before the full File Upload ("Open") dialog opens, possibly due to resizing or maybe enumerating disk drives and system folders. I suggest you open Chrome in a private window and disable all your extensions. Also try another PC or VM.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, this has been the case on several PCs. The behavior is the same on a private window. Wonder what this could be.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I'm running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, not Windows 10 (I was thinking about another PC that I use.)

Comment: I'm on windows 7 enterprise 64 bit. Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Just wondering, have you tested normal (non-Angular/JS) file uploads in your environment in Chrome? E.g. I just made this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9Ld1tbyf/ which only has standard HTML file upload/submit controls. Do you experience the 5-second delay with that fiddle? (I don't.) And are all the PCs you tested on running the same corporate network? Maybe there is a mapped drive or other shared resource that is only shown in Chrome file upload dialogs and is delaying the process.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I do see the delay with the fiddle, so I guess it's something browser related? Yeah, every PC running on the same corporate network. Gave me the idea to check other apps and have the same issue on chrome only and those aren't angular apps. So I should investigate if there is a shared drive only coming up on chrome upload dialogs?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like there is something in your corporate environment delaying the Chrome upload dialogs (not specific to AngularJS or even JavaScript.) There might be a shared drive in Windows Explorer or some kind of Windows context/Explorer-menu addon causing the delay. It might be visible in all browsers, but something about Chrome's use of the file selection dialog (which can sometimes be a standard Windows API call) might be susceptible to the delay.

Comment: Thanks, after disconnecting all network drives I still have the lag. But yeah, I think you have steered me towards the right direction of something corporate environment related with Chrome usage. Will keep digging. Thanks a lot for your efforts Jordan!